# How to change root commit for all branches?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a repository with multiple branches besides `master` and while it is not public I would like to re-write the very first commit (update dependencies versions in a build script). If I only had one branch I would simply `git rebase -i -r --root`, and amend changes to root commit. The problem is that it rebases only current branch while others still point to the history with an old root.

```
              B11-B12 (feature1)
             /
root-M2-M3-M4-M5-M6 (master)
         \
          B21-B22-B23 (feature2)
```

How can I change root commit and re-assign all branches to corresponding commits in a history with a new root?

Comment: Use `git rebase --root` in conjunction with `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+all+branches